# Apache httpd.conf restrict access to parent using Alias

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

I have an Alias for a directory

```
Alias /out /myData/all
<Directory /myData/all >
    Options Indexes MultiViews
     AllowOverride None
     Order deny,allow
     Allow from all
</Directory>
```

myData/all has many subdirectories of different projects. When someone accesses host/out/project01 through a direct link, I would like to restrict their ability to to click **Parent Directory** and see all project folders under out. Is this possible with the alias?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about something like:

```
http://example.com/out/project01/..
                                 ^^--- "up a level" link
```

then the actual requested page would be

```
http://example.com/out/
```

which is aliased to the `/myData/all` directory. Since that directory has indexes enabled (`Options Indexes`) they could browse all the projects.

Either turn off indexes, or move your aliases down a level:

```
Alias /out /myData/all/project01
```

so that moving up a level:

```
http://example.com/out/..
```

simply takes you to

```
http://example.com/
```

Comment: I cannot move my alias down a level. I tried removing Options Indexes but then I got a Forbidden you dont have permission error when I tried to access a subdirectory

Comment: which usually means there's no default document (e.g. `index.html`) available, and since browsing's disabled, you get forbidden.

Comment: subdirectories are directories of files not a page, I should of specified that

Comment: doesn't matter. if you don't specify a file (`.../out/somefile.html`) and browsing is disabled (`../out/`) and there's no default document in the directory, it WILL be seen as a browse attempt and you get forbidden.